# Change url to default page next.js

Tags: next.js

I tried to find how to change the default page path (when you access the server on the "/" path) but couldn't find anything. I have a structure in the pages directory in the form index/index.jsx and I want this page to be returned by default when accessing the server. I did not find a similar question on this forum, maybe someone will need your help, except me.

Answer (score 2):

The way pages structure works in Next.js is very opiniated. If you need to send a file from a different pages structure when accessing `/` you would need to configure your own little express server.

[See this link for official doc.](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

You would then have something like :

```
// Some code

if (pathname === '/') {
    app.render(req, res, '/index', query) // Or /index/index.jsx
}

// Some code
```

Also if you do not want to create your own express server, you could have an index.js that redirects to your index page with something like this :

```
import Router from 'next/router'

const Index = () => null

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ res }) => {
    if (res) {
        res.writeHead(302, {
            Location: `/index`
        })
        res.end()
    } 
    else
        Router.push(`/index`)

    return {}
}

export default Index
```

Comment: but I do not have a custom server, I would like to know if I can do it with next.config.js.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve ?
When accessing `/` do you want : 
1. To send another file than `/pages/index.js` ?
2. Have another url than `/` ?